# Play multiple file in Read application [Asterisk platform]

Tags: user-input, asterisk, playback

The way i can getting user input is `Read` application as follow:
`Read(variable[,filename[,maxDigits[,option[,attempts[,timeout]]]]])`
But if i want to play multiple file instead of one file to get user input, it doesn't have any option! I can use `Playback` or `Background` to play files and then call `Read` application, but user can not input during sound play.

[Asterisk Read application](http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/applikationen-read.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [voip-info](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read) in Asterisk version 1.4, you cannot do that, but in 1.8, you can specify multiple sound files by separating them with the '&' symbols. (Playback and Background also support this method of playing multiple sounds)

I'm not sure if the feature is supported in 1.6 or not.

Comment: it is supported in 1.6.X too.